# Android Studio with multiple GitHub repositories and multiple pcs

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

Let me tell you what I would like to achieve in case the title is not helpful. Since I lack knowledge, I might not use the right technical terms.

I want to be able to work on 2 different Android applications and I want to be able to work on them either from home or from my laptop when I commute.

For this reason I created 2 repositories on GitHub (I ended up it is less pain to do it this way).

How do I configure Android Studio for multiple repositories? How do I make sure that I do not try to apply changes to the wrong repository?

How do I switch repository?

Can I do it from inside Android Studio or I have to use command line?

After I get some burning comments I will elaborate more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, when you open Android Studio it recognises that there is VCS configured, reads all the repositories and gives options to select which one you need to load.

I will update my answer as soon as I find more details out!

Comment: I have a project with custom library. Both (wrapper project and library) are committed to separate repos. Android Studio currently just detects the wrapper project. How can I use VCS tools on library files as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use submodules for your project. But each project has to be done in independent git repo if you don't want to use submodules. VCS will be confused if you would like to have 2 different repos in one folder.